# re-arrange Matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

a matrix I am working with looks like this . It is square

```
  structure(c(3, 4, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 3, 9), .Dim = c(5L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(c("a1", 
    "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5"), c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5")))
```

I need to add up the elements below and above the triagonal and empty the upper triangle of the matrix. The result looks like this

```
         structure(c(3, 4, 2, 4, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9), .Dim = c(5L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(c("a1", 
"a2", "a3", "a4", "a5"), c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5")))
```

is there an efficient way to do that? So just add upt the values of lower and upper half in the lower half of the element -

Comment: no , please look at the difference in m[3,2] and m[2,3] - the element is added up 2 and 1 - is 3

Comment: Please check the solution below.  It gives the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

We can try

```
m1[lower.tri(m1)] <- m1[lower.tri(m1)] + t(m1)[lower.tri(m1)] 
m1[upper.tri(m1)] <- 0
identical(m1, m2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: so that would work also when we use your solution matr[row.names(m1), colnames(m1)] <- matr[row.names(m1), colnames(m1)] + m1 from the previous question right - so get the whole matrix and then summarise?

Comment: what is the code doing with the diagonal though? it is setting it to zero right? because the diagonal is counted to be in the upper triangle by R>

Comment: @kutyw I am not touching the diagonal and kept it as such.  If you still think this is not the expected,....